# Why only first page data could get when using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I use the python package selenium to click the "load more" button automatically, which is successful. But why do I cannot get data after "load more"?

I want to crawl reviews from HP.com using python. It only displays few monitors until I click "load more" button. I use the python package selenium to click the "load more" button automatically, which is successful. But why do I cannot get data after "load more" and just get the first page data repeatedly?

And I tried to use "wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located)" but it didn't run whatever I use... so I chose hardcode like waiting specific seconds. If anyone can help to find how to recode, it'll be super appreciated....

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/plp/accessories/computer-monitors"
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"}

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python310\chromedriver.exe")
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/plp/accessories/computer-monitors")

loadmore = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#content > div.clearfix.vwa > div.product-results.product-results.left-menu-open > div.search-results > span')

count = 0
while count < 5:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(3)
    loadmore.click()
    time.sleep(3) 
    count+=1

import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
prods = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class":"product-title pdp-link"})
for prod in prods :
    print(prod.get_text())
```

Comment: I see that you are clicking the load more button (span in this case) with selenium but you then parse the "a" tags with the requests package which is a complete different request. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"}

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={headers}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
#Service("C:\Python310\chromedriver.exe") also works here
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get("https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/plp/accessories/computer-monitors")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.caclose"))).click()

count=0
while count<5:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.search-load-more"))).click()
        count+=1
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        break

texts=[x.text for x in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.product-title.pdp-link")))]
print(texts)
```

There's an element proceeding from my region's site so I closed it.
If you want to click the load more 5 times or just use while True for until it disappears. Then grab all the text just wait for visibility and use .text.

Imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Outputs:

```
['HP M24FW FHD MONITOR', 'HP M27F FHD MONITOR', 'HP M24F FHD MONITOR', 'HP V241IB FHD MONITOR', 'HP 27F 27-INCH 4K DISPLAY', 'HP V24 FHD MONITOR', 'HP P22H G4 FHD MONITOR', 'HP U28 4K HDR MONITOR', 'HP Z24U G3 WUXGA USB-C DISPLAY', 'HP V20 HD+ MONITOR', 'HP E27 G4 FHD MONITOR', 'HP E24Q G4 QHD MONITOR', 'HP 27MQ 27-INCH MONITOR', 'HP E27U G4 QHD USB-C MONITOR', 'HP U27 4K WIRELESS MONITOR', 'HP M27FD FHD MONITOR', 'HP X34 WQHD GAMING MONITOR', 'HP X27C FHD GAMING MONITOR', 'HP X32C FHD GAMING MONITOR']
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But with this code, the webdriver is automatically shutdown without any load-more, shows null data as below..

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.caclose"))).click()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF69A3+2582947]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A8A6D1+2139857]
        Ordinal0 [0x00983A98+1063576]
        Ordinal0 [0x009AFF3E+1244990]
        Ordinal0 [0x009B013B+1245499]
        Ordinal0 [0x009D9F52+1417042]...

Comment: Swap that one it's a popup that occurs depending on where your from it seems.

Answer (score 0):

When you access this site with a fresh browser, after a delay, a dialog asking you to accept their privacy policy will appear. So the solution is to wait for and click the accept button before trying to click on load more.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
```

For this code to work you need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[Here is a runnable example I made](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/d55fe0bc-16a8-4757-8545-f65b6b7f9d9c?projectId=bugtestproject2)

Comment: This is great point. I added code for pause a while until Privacy policy popup.